# Redesign first td in html table to rowspan

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have table like this:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Col1</th>
         <th>Col2</th>
         <th>Col3</th>
         <th>Col4</th>
         <th>Col5</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
       <td class="control"></td>
       <td>AA</td>
       <td>BB</td>
       <td>CC</td>
       <td>DD</td>
       <td>EE</td>
   </tr>
   ...
</table>
```

Due page resize I want to change that table to be like following table design. The change should applied on odd rows only because the even rows hidden and it's shows when I click on the first `td` that has control class.

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td rowspan="6" class="control"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Col1</td>
       <td>AA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Col2</td>
       <td>BB</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Col3</td>
       <td>CC</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
       <td>Col4</td>
       <td>DD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Col5</td>
       <td>EE</td>
    </tr>
   ...
```

Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/pmtgqmsa/2/

Comment: How about two different tables and playing with `visibility` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm not sure if that can be done with css or javascript but I prefered to have one table and change it by javascript

Comment: I'm not saying your case is not possible but dealing with 2 different tables would be better approach if DOM stricture is not too heavy. In this way, you are not troubling browser much..

Comment: @RayonDabre in your case I have to fill the data twice from database that make some performance issue

Comment: Anyhow, JS manipulations are going to take CPU cycles as well..Anyways, show us what have you tried..

Comment: It looks as if the td designated as columns are just the first (second?) column tds. Any th would be in the same row as `.control`. Did you want 5 columns, 5 rows, or both?

Comment: @zer00ne check the link in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've tried several times then I got the answer

```
$('#myTable > thead > tr').css('display', 'none');
    $('#myTable tr.parent').each(function () {
        var _html = "";
        var _newRow = "";
        var header = Array();
        $("#myTable  tr th").each(function (i) {
            header[i] = $(this).text();
        });
        $(this).find('td').each(function (i) {                
                if (i == 0) {
                    _html += "<td rowspan='6'>" + $(this).html() + "</td>";
                }
                else {
                    _newRow += "<tr> <td> " + header[i] + " :</td> <td>" + $(this).html() + "</td> </tr>";
                }
        })
        $(this).html("");
        $(this).html(_html);
        $(_newRow).insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"));            
    })
```

I hope my answer help anyone looking for similar code

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex box in order to achieve that kind of task.

flex-box capable to change the current flow of the content from row to column. just by changing `flex-flow: column;` to `flex-flow: row;`

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/btLja1qz/)

You can learn more about flex-box in [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Since it is div now, you won't have the row/col span problem also. You can adjust the height and width freely.

Comment: While it's a nice idea, the fiddle you show doesn't solve his problem. It's only changing n items in a row to n items in a column. He wants something more involved, where the order is not the same

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for your code but I have to use the table instead of div. even that this not matching what I'm looking for as the above description